django-ckeditor-5 media embed config for youtube shorts
I am having django project with django-ckeditor-5 package.
The default media providers of ckeditor-5 has youtube. However, I could find from the original source that the regex for youtube do not include shorts url.
So, I had to add extraProviders. I tried various ways, but none of them worked.
"mediaEmbed": {
    "previewsInData": "true",
    "extraProviders": [
        {
            "name": "youtube-shorts",
            "url": [
                r"^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube\.com\/shorts\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$",
                r"/^(?:m\.)?youtube\.com\/shorts\/(.+)/",
            ],
            "html": (
                '<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;">'
                '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{matched}" '
                'style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;" '
                'frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>'
                "</iframe>"
                "</div>"
            ),
        },
    ],
},

this is one of the method I tried, and it gives the below error.

If I use like below for allowing all it works without the preview image like the screenshot below though.
mediaEmbed": {
    "previewsInData": "true",
    "extraProviders": [
        {
            "name": "all",
            "url": r"/^.+/",
        },
    ],
},


Anyone had experience make this work?
==========update=========
I gave up adding it to settings, but tried using javascript to override the configs like below.
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
    const editor = document.querySelector('.ck-editor-container');

    const config = {
      "toolbar": [
        "heading",
        "|",
        "bold",
        "italic",
        "link",
        "bulletedList",
        "numberedList",
        "blockQuote",
        "imageUpload",
        "mediaEmbed",
      ],
      "mediaEmbed": {
        "previewsInData": "true",
        "extraProviders": [{
          name: 'youtube-shorts',
          url: [
            /^(?:m\.)?youtube\.com\/shorts\/([\w-]+)(?:\?t=(\d+))?/
          ],
          html: match => {
            const id = match[1];
            const time = match[2];

            return (
              '<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;">' +
              `<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${ id }${ time ? `?start=${ time }` : '' }" ` +
              'style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;" ' +
              'frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>' +
              '</iframe>' +
              '</div>'
            );
          }
        }, ],
      },
    };

    ClassicEditor.create(editor, config)
      .then(editor => {
        console.log("Editor was initialized", editor);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("There was a problem initializing the editor", error);
      });
  </script>
{% endblock javascript %}

This works perfectly on the form, however, the content is saving just nothing. In database, I can see only <p>&nbsp;</p>.
I investigated more and found out it is not overriding the existed one, but creating new and bring it up front to hide the old one.

I used const editor = document.querySelector('.ck-editor-container'); this instead const editor = window.editors["id_content"]; that is from django-ckeditor-5 documentation because when running server it returns "undefined".
However, when I test on browser console it returns the correct editor.

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

FYI, youtube shorts url regex is added on ckeditor default Media Embed. And django-ckeditor-5 package is updated. so, it is solved.
